# How to check when the Ubuntu server was rebooted?

Tags: command-line, reboot

I need to know when my server was rebooted? I only see my last login when I login.

Where is this info stored?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `last` to see login information. To know about system reboot, enter in a terminal,

```
last | grep reboot
```

Answer (score 13):

You can run the `uptime` command from the console to see how long the server has been running. This will give the total amount of time since the last reboot.

Comment: thank you, funny that I didn't know that command yet. Happy that I now added it to my brain hard drive

Answer (score 7):

- `who -b`
- `uptime`
- `last reboot`
- `ll /var/log/ | grep boot.log`